# Data Exchange Framework - Multiple CopyObjectFromContextToNewLocationStepConverter

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Using `Sitecore 9.0.1`, and `DEF 2.0.1`, we are importing `experiences` from an API.

This experience json contains `point geometries` and `trail uses`

The Pipeline steps `Handle Point Geometries` and `Get Trail Uses to a New Destination` are both of type `Copy Object from Context to New Location Pipeline Step`

But, the Point Geometry data is being passed to the Trail Uses steps, presumably because the Source Object Location for the trail uses step is picking up the data from Iterate Point Geometries.

How do I get the `Get Trail Uses` step to use data from the Experience, not the Point Geometries?

Iterate Point Geometries and Run Pipelines - Iterable Data Location: Pipeline Context Iterable Data

Iterate Point Geometries and Run Pipelines - Data Location: Pipeline Context Source

Get Trail Uses to a new Destination - Source Object Location: Pipeline Context Source

[image]